# Pickman's Blade is a Nuka Cola?

Tags: fallout-4

At the top of a tool box I was looting, I saw 'Pickman's Blade' with a star next to it. Currently running a sniper build in the game, I was super excited because this was an easy find for something that would be super useful. I took the blade....and was given a Nuka Cola. Is this normal, or did the game glitch?

I received the 'blade' near the Museum of Freedom in a small campground next to the fire.

Comment: Bug. And that sucks. It's a decent knife. I'd recommend "hacking" it if you really didn't get it.

Answer (score 4):

This is almost certainly a bug. Pickman's Blade is a unique combat knife, and should only be found in a safe in the Pickman Gallery.

If you start seeing this issue (incorrect item names) often, and you play on PC, try verifying your game files.