# Why does a holotape in Gunners Plaza weigh 17.4 pounds?

Tags: fallout-4

I was going throughout Gunners Plaza when I came across a holotape in Captain Wes' safe. It was titled 'Automatic Assault Rifle', and weighed 17.4 pounds, about as much as an assault rifle. The holotape went into my Misc. section when taken, not Weapons, and when I played the holotape it's about a group of gunners having to retreat back to HQ--the Gunners Plaza.

Did the game glitch the name and weight of the holotape, or is it supposed to be a holotape that surprisingly weighs far more than it should and has a name that doesn't really make sense?

Comment: This sounds like a bug.  It was probably suppose to be an Assault Rifle, but for some reason its being recognized as a holotape with either all or some of the properties of the Assault Rifle.  I would just drop it so you don't have the burden of wasted weight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The item you are describing should have the name *Wes' holotape*, and a weight of zero. This is a glitch, likely caused by the corruption of game files. Given that [you've had similar issues in the past](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/291159/81131), I suggest you verify your game files (if playing on PC), or deleting/reinstalling the game if playing on a console.